# Julia: Split module into multiple files

Tags: module, julia

I am using Julia v0.6.4. Consider the following module, saved in `FooModule.jl`:

```
module FooModule

export Foo
export doSomething

mutable struct Foo
    x::Int64
    function Foo(xin::Int64)
        new(xin)
    end # Foo
end # struct

function doSomething(F::Foo)
    println(F.x+123)
end # doSomething

end # module
```

And a `main.jl`:

```
using FooModule
function main()
F = Foo(10)
doSomething(F)
end # main
```

Now I start the Julia REPL:

```
julia> include("main.jl");

julia> main()
133
```

I.e. I get what I expect.
Now imagine `doSomething` contains many lines and I want to split `FooModule.jl`. I would like to do something like this:

```
module FooModule

export Foo
export doSomething

include("doSomething.jl")        # <- include instead of writing out

mutable struct Foo
    x::Int64
    function Foo(xin::Int64)
        new(xin)
    end # Foo
end # struct

end # module
```

and `doSomething.jl`

```
function doSomething(F::Foo)
    println(F.x+123)
end # doSomething
```

This gives an error since `doSomething.jl` knows nothing about `Foo`.

```
julia> include("main.jl");
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: Foo not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [2] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [3] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [4] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
 [5] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:490
 [6] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:405
 [7] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [8] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
while loading ~/Desktop/doSomething.jl, in expression starting on line 1
while loading ~/Desktop/FooModule.jl, in expression starting on line 6
while loading ~/Desktop/main.jl, in expression starting on line 1
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just move the `include("doSomething.jl")` to where the function was originally, i.e. *after* the type definition. You can think of `include` as copy-pasting the code into the file.

Comment: Nice short and sweet explanation.

Comment: What if  `doSomething` required from importing a module (ie. `LinearAlgebra`) would you code the `using LinearAlgebra` in `doSomething.jl` or in `FooModule.jl`.

Moreover, what if `LinearAlgebra` was also required in `FooModule`, would you write it in both (`FooModule.jl` and `doSomething.jl`)? What is the good practice here?

Comment: Most packages keep all `using` or `import` at the toplevel module.